# What does Process Default (Entire Database) SSIS Task actually do?

Tags: ssis, ssas

I (probably quite naively) set up an SSIS package to process my SSAS database nightly.

I read that setting the granularity at "Database" would ensure I processed both Measure groups and Dimensions.

However a couple of my cubes had not processed for a few days.

I thought that Process Default (selecting the entire database) would bring all objects "up to date"

I am thinking that may not be the case. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is to do a "Full process" of the database. Do not use "Default" processing, as this is mainly useful during development, when you tend to change structures of objects of the cube, but the data content does not change. Then it optimizes processing, only processing the parts of the cube affected by the structural change.

Default processing detects the state of all objects like dimensions, cubes, measure groups, partitions, aggregations. The state can be any of processed, unprocessed, or partly processed. Process default brings the partly or unprocessed objects to processed state. It does not check if any data has changed on the relational data source, it just checks the state of the objects in the database.
An object can get to unprocessed state in one of the following ways:

- If you newly create it.
- If you change the objects structure. making sub objects just visible or invisible does not change the structure, nor does renaming sub objects in most cases, but adding or removing sub objects does.
- If you explicitly unprocess it (using the Unprocess or Clear process options of the process command).
- If you process an object on which the current object depends, and do that in a way that does not keep relations. E. g. if you do a full process of a dimension, all measure groups related to the dimension will get unprocessed. If you do a "Process Update" of the dimensions, the measure groups stay processed.

Answer (score 2):

When there is a lot data processing Entire Database can not work.

The real thing is that you insert 2 SSIS processing elements (Dimensions must be processed first):

1 SSIS element processing **all dimensions**

2 SSIS element processing **all cubes**

```
Dimension processing->Cubes processing
```

Processing options must be done in **Full Processing**, then all data will be processed. Of course this processing is the longest.

Comment: You can also have just one processing step "Process database". But it should be "process full", not "process default".

Comment: I have done one time Entire database processing, but after some time the cube didn't process... I really don't remember what processing was full or default... after that I process dimensions first and then Cubes.

Comment: We do full database processing in 95 percent of cases, and never had an issue with that. "Default processing" is mainly targeted for development time. As far as I understand it, it checks which objects are unprocessed, and processes these. An object can get unprocessed in several ways: if you do an explicit unprocess, if you process an object on which the object depends in a "non conservative" way, e. g. if you do a full process of a dimension, then all related measure groups get unprocessed, and finally, if you change the structure of the object, or an object on which it depends.